# Is there a similar way to export constants (using constantsToExport) from native module on Android as on iOS?

Tags: react-native

I have been working on a React Native app with native modules. It would be nice to be able to export enums defined on the native side to JS side. On iOS, you can define a constantsToExport method in your Native Module like documented [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html):

```
- (NSDictionary *)constantsToExport
{
    return @{ @"firstDayOfTheWeek": @"Monday" };
}
```

However, there doesn't seem to be such a nice way on Android. Am I missing anything or it's simply not provided? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

According to docs : http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.41/docs/native-modules-android.html#native-modules

you don't need to put your constants in BaseJavaModule.java 
every class that `extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule` have an optional method `getConstants()`

> An optional method called getConstants returns the constant values
>   exposed to JavaScript. Its implementation is not required but is very
>   useful to key pre-defined values that need to be communicated from
>   JavaScript to Java in sync.

```
@Override
  public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
    final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
    constants.put(DURATION_SHORT_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    constants.put(DURATION_LONG_KEY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    return constants;
  }
```

Comment: Well I meant override this method in your subclasses. Thanks for making this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question to help people who may encounter this problem later. In `BaseJavaModule.java` file, there is following method:

```
/**
 * @return a map of constants this module exports to JS. Supports JSON types.
 */
public @Nullable Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
  return null;
}
```

This lets you export constants to JavaScript. Should be in the documentation though.